# Can't allow guests to access some routes

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

hi guys i have problem that when a guest visits my website can't proceed to some links and will be redirected to login page I am using laravel with vuejs 
i have changed in routes.js from 'userAuth: true' to userNotAuth: true but it doesn't work it always redirect to login page
routes.js

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
```

let themeName = document.body.firstElementChild.className;

let routes = [

```
{
    name: 'login',
    path: '/app/login',
    component: require('../views/' + themeName + '/auth/login'),
    meta: {
        userNotAuth: true,
        title: 'Login'
    }
},

{
    name: 'plan',
    path: '/app/signup/plan',
    component: require('../views/' + themeName + '/auth/plan'),
    meta: {
        userNotAuth: true,
        title: 'Subscriber Plan'
    }
},
{
    name: 'signup',
    path: '/app/signup',
    component: require('../views/' + themeName + '/auth/register'),
    meta: {
        userNotAuth: true,
        title: 'Signup'
    }
},
{
    name: 'forget_password',
    path: '/app/forget',
    component: require('../views/' + themeName + '/auth/forget-password'),
    meta: {
        userNotAuth: true,
        title: 'Forget Password'
    }
},

{
    name: 'forget_change',
    path: '/app/forget/rest/:code',
    component: require('../views/' + themeName + '/auth/forget-rest'),
    meta: {
        userNotAuth: true,
        title: 'Forget Password'

    }
},

{
    name: 'privacy',
    path: '/app/privacy',
    component: require('../views/' + themeName + '/control/footer/privacy'),
    meta: {
        allAuth: true,
        title: 'Privacy'
    }
},
{
    name: 'terms',
    path: '/app/terms',
    component: require('../views/' + themeName + '/control/footer/terms'),
    meta: {
        allAuth: true,
        title: 'Terms'
    }
},
{
    name: 'contact-us',
    path: '/app/contact-us',
    component: require('../views/' + themeName + '/control/footer/contact-us'),
    meta: {
        allAuth: true,
        name: 'Contact Us',
    }
},
{
    name: 'about-us',
    path: '/app/about-us',
    component: require('../views/' + themeName + '/control/footer/about-us'),
    meta: {
        allAuth: true,
        title: 'About Us',
    }
},



{
    name: 'payment',
    path: '/app/signup/payment',
    component: require('../views/' + themeName + '/auth/payment'),
    meta: {
        userPaymentAuth: true,
        title: 'Payment'
    }
},
{
    name: 'signup-non-payment',
    path: '/app/signup',
    component: require('../views/' + themeName + '/auth/register-non-payment.vue'),
    meta: {
        userNotAuth: true,
        title: 'Signup'
    }
},

{
    name: '404',
    path: '/app/404',
    component: require('../views/' + themeName + '/errors/404'),
    meta: {
        title: 'Not Found',
    }
},



{
    name: 'discover',
    path: '/app',
    component: require('../views/' + themeName + '/control/home'),
    meta: {
        allAuth: true,
        title: 'Discover'
    },
},

{
    name: 'movies',
    path: '/app/movies',
    component: require('../views/' + themeName + '/control/movie/movies'),
    meta: {
        allAuth: true,
        title: 'Movies'
    },
},
{
    name: 'show-movie',
    path: '/app/show/:id',
    component: require('../views/' + themeName + '/control/movie/show'),
    meta: {
        allAuth: true,
        metaTags: [
            {
                name: 'description',
                content: 'The about page of our example app.'
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
    name: 'series',
    path: '/app/series',
    component: require('../views/' + themeName + '/control/series/series'),
    meta: {
        allAuth: true,
        title: 'Tv Show'
    },
},

{
    name: 'show-series',
    path: '/app/series/show/:id',
    component: require('../views/' + themeName + '/control/series/show'),
    meta: {
        allAuth: true,
        title: 'Show Series',
        metaTags: [
            {
                name: 'description',
                content: 'The about page of our example app.'
            }
            ]
    },

},
{
    name: 'kids',
    path: '/app/kids',
    component: require('../views/' + themeName + '/control/kids/kids'),
    meta: {
        allAuth: true,
        title: 'Kids'
    },
},
{
    name: 'channels',
    path: '/app/channels',
    component: require('../views/' + themeName + '/control/channels/channels'),
    meta: {
        allAuth: true,
        title: 'Live Tv'
    }
},
{
    name: 'collection',
    path: '/app/collection/:id',
    component: require('../views/' + themeName + '/control/collection/index.vue'),
    meta: {
        userAuth: true,
        title: 'My Collections'
    },
},

{
    name: 'series-player',
    path: '/app/watch/series/:series_id',
    component: require('../views/' + themeName + '/control/video-player/series-player'),
    meta: {
        userAuth: true,
        title: 'Series Player'
    }
},
{
    name: 'series-player-sp',
    path: '/app/watch/series/:series_id/:episode_id',
    component: require('../views/' + themeName + '/control/video-player/series-player'),
    meta: {
        userAuth: true,
        title: 'Series Player'
    }
},
{
    name: 'movie-player',
    path: '/app/watch/movie/:id',
    component: require('../views/' + themeName + '/control/video-player/movie-player'),
    meta: {
        userAuth: true,
        title: 'Movie Player'

    }
},


{
    name: 'tv-player',
    path: '/app/watch/tv/:id',
    component: require('../views/' + themeName + '/control/video-player/tv-player'),
    meta: {
        userAuth: true,
        title: 'Tv Player'
    }
},
{
    name: 'search',
    path: '/app/search',
    component: require('../views/' + themeName + '/control/search/search'),
    meta: {
        userAuth: true,
        title: 'Search'
    },
},
{
    name: 'cast',
    path: '/app/cast/:id',
    component: require('../views/' + themeName + '/control/search/cast'),
    meta: {
        userAuth: true,
        title: 'Cast'
    },
},

{
    name: 'profile',
    path: '/app/setting/public',
    component: require('../views/' + themeName + '/control/setting/profile'),
    meta: {
        userAuth: true,
        title: 'Profile'
    }
},
{
    name: 'security',
    path: '/app/setting/security',
    component: require('../views/' + themeName + '/control/setting/security'),
    meta: {
        userAuth: true,
        title: 'Security'
    }
},

{
    name: 'payment-update',
    path: '/app/setting/payment-update',
    component: require('../views/' + themeName + '/control/setting/payment-update'),
    meta: {
        userAuth: true,
        title: 'Payment Update'
    }
},

{
    name: 'billing-details',
    path: '/app/setting/billing-details',
    component: require('../views/' + themeName + '/control/setting/billing-details'),
    meta: {
        userAuth: true,
        title: 'Billing Details'
    }
},
{
    name: 'change-plan',
    path: '/app/setting/change-plan',
    component: require('../views/' + themeName + '/control/setting/change-plan'),
    meta: {
        userAuth: true,
        title: 'Change Your Plan'
    }
},
{
    name: 'language',
    path: '/app/setting/language',
    component: require('../views/' + themeName + '/control/setting/language'),
    meta: {
        userAuth: true,
        title: 'Language'
    }
},

{
    name: 'adjust-subtitles',
    path: '/app/setting/adjust-subtitles',
    component: require('../views/' + themeName + '/control/setting/adjust-subtitles'),
    meta: {
        userAuth: true,
        title: 'Adjust subtitles'
    }
},

{
    name: 'viewing-history',
    path: '/app/setting/viewing-history',
    component: require('../views/' + themeName + '/control/setting/viewing-history.vue'),
    meta: {
        userAuth: true,
        title: 'viewing History'
    }
},

{
    name: 'support-inbox',
    path: '/app/setting/support-inbox',
    component: require('../views/' + themeName + '/control/setting/support-inbox.vue'),
    meta: {
        userAuth: true,
        title: 'Support Inbox'
    }
},

{
    name: 'support-request',
    path: '/app/setting/support-request/:id',
    component: require('../views/' + themeName + '/control/setting/support-request.vue'),
    meta: {
        userAuth: true,
        title: 'Support Request'
    }
},

{
    name: 'device-activity',
    path: '/app/setting/device-activity',
    component: require('../views/' + themeName + '/control/setting/device-activity.vue'),
    meta: {
        userAuth: true,
        title: 'Device Activity'
    }
},
```

];

export default new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes,
    scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
        if (savedPosition) {
            return savedPosition;
        } else {
            return {x: 0, y: 0};
        }
    }
});

Comment: In you controller constructor check $this->middleware('auth'); This will check if the user is logged in. If they're not logged in they will be redirected

Comment: Are you sure it's `userNotAuth: true` instead of `userAuth: false`?

Comment: i tried also userAuth:false  but doesn't work

Comment: name: 'movie-player',
    path: '/app/watch/movie/:id',
    component: require('../views/' + themeName + '/control/video-player/movie-player'),
    meta: {
        userAuth: true,
        title: 'Movie Player'

    }    i need that one to be accessed to all guest

Comment: Should i run composer once i do changes in the js file???